# Team Foundation Server : how to get multiple item using wildcards

Tags: tfs

We are using Team Foundation (2008) as our source control.

I'm wondering if there is any way to recursively get multiple files using wildcards?

For instance :

```
*.txt
*.rc
*.h
*.cs
```

etc.

Thanks a lot,

Nic

Comment: Where do you want multiple items? For what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you're talking about programmatically or from the command line, there's not a single solution to be able to do what you want.  You'll need to iterate through each of your wildcards and append them to the rest of the ItemSpec path as part of your get.